# SQL show detail rows and aggregates for different time periods on same row

Tags: sql

Let's say I have a query which retrieves individual supplier transactions. I need to keep that details but on each row I would also like to see monthly, quarterly, and annual totals for each supplier. How would I go about this?

Currently my query output looks like this

Date      Month     Quarter    Year    Supplier     Value

I'd like it to produce SupplierMonthlyTotal, SupplierQuarterlyTotal, SupplierAnnualTotal columns as well.

Comment: Which RDBMS (Oracle, SQLServer, PostgreSQL, etc) are you using?

Comment: eh yeah i'm using SQL server

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use analytic function `SUM ... OVER ... PARTITION BY` ([see documentation for Oracle](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions182.htm#i89126)).

Here you have general informations about analytic functions: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm

Comment: Note that analytic functions are not supported by all RDBMSs.

Comment: hmmm im using sql server is there any equivalent?